# Query execution timing method

Tags: mysql

I am running this join query with count and it certainly took nearly an hour to generate an output as there were thousands of records. But when it finished executing it says,

`Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 11,851 total, Query took 31.9122 sec)`

May I please know what timing mechanism is used by mysql? cause it certainly didn't take 31 seconds :)

thank you very much..

**PS:** if this issue was addressed before, please direct me to it. i didn't know what to look for in this situation.

**Extra info:**
Mysql running on XAMPP v3.0.12 on Windows Vista 32bit, intel Core2Quad Q8400 @ 2.66Ghz, 4GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The query itself may have only taken 31.9122 seconds but something else in your execution of the command took much longer. For example, how are you connected to the system?

Comment: thank you for the reply..i ran this query through phpmyadmin and i ran the query on the same pc where the database is held :)

Comment: I wonder if it's not disk access that caused the query to crawl. Not sure, I guess. :-\

Comment: hmmmm...u mean to say slow access of the hard disk or lack of space? yeaa may be..anyway thank you for the reply :)

Comment: Yes, I mean slow accessing the hard disk. I'm not sure what kind of data you're returning.